# Manhattan distance to drive the search in NxN 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like to know how to use the Manhattan Distance heuristic to drive my search in NxN 2d array. I have the following Manhattan distance:

```
private int manhattan(int[] pos, int tile) {
        int[] dest = new int[] {
            (tile - 1) % BOARDSIZE, (tile - 1) / BOARDSIZE
        };
        return Math.abs(dest[0] - pos[0]) + Math.abs(dest[1] - pos[1]);
    }
```

I will be moving tiles to the empty tile to LEFT, RIGHT, UP or DOWN. How do I use the above function to select neighbours of a node in order to add to a queue? Do I have to put it in a double for loop or? I am using `f = g+h`.

I am a beginner in puzzles so am struggling a little bit to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you've rewritten your earlier question. The question you pose is explored in detail in [Russell and Norvig's Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136042597). Read the 3rd chapter. Check out their website at http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/. They even have code for A* there, with a link to a demo of the [8 puzzle](http://www.permadi.com/java/puzzle8/).